# Jquery Supersized: load slideshow into specific div

Tags: jquery, supersized

It seems [Jquery Supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized) currently allows only attach background image(s) for whole BODY? Is it possible to use a css selector to tell him where to load background slideshow?

I've tried something like

```
$('#custom-div').supersized();
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I dont know exactly what you mean, but if I can be of any help, I've got a few supersized things running like this one: http://www.krijnen.com/opcafe.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a great slider-[Nerve](http://www.ryanbruzan.net/work/projects/nerve-slider), it is a little more simple but easy to customize. And it can be full screen or in a div.

I was, actually, trying to do the same thing with SUPERSIZED and could not get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div with id="supersized" in your HTML, and it will load there. I only tested this briefly, but it looks like it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try these instructions, they work great :)
http://arushad.org/how-to-use-supersized-inside-a-div-for-a-background-image-slideshow

Comment: I just followed the instruction and got the proper slider, very simple one for background, what I've seeking. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yea it [seems](https://github.com/buildinternet/supersized/blob/master/core/js/supersized.core.3.2.1.js#L17-19)
 like Supersized is only for full-screen backgrounds.

I would suggest something like [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) :)